# Что такое Instance в C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Недавно начал баловаться с unity, стал смотреть примеры скриптов и наткнулся на такую конструкцию:

```
public class MakeFX : MonoBehaviour

{
    private static MakeFX instance;
    public static MakeFX Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<MakeFX>();
            return instance;
        }
    }
    ... 
}
```

После С++ для меня такая конструкция выглядит странно. Погуглив справку в msdn лучше не стало. Объясните, что это такое и зачем оно надо.

Comment: Это свойство. Читайте любую начальную книгу по C#.

Comment: instance - это экземпляр объекта. В данном случае реализован паттерн Singleton, позволяющий создать всего один экземпляр указанного типа для всего приложения.

Comment: @qzavyer Я бы рекомендовал вам оформить ваш комментарий как ответ, ибо он самый понятный из всех :) И еще, могли бы вы привести пример, как это использовать без Singleton'а, т.е. чтобы я мог создать больше, чем один объект, используя instance, если это реализуемо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения языка C# - это самое обычное имя свойства. С английского языка это слово переводится как "экземпляр".

Чаще всего подобное статическое свойство можно встретить при реализации шаблона проектирования (паттерна) "Одиночка" (Singleton).

Отмечу, что приведенный вами код не является канонической реализацией, поскольку единственный экземпляр класса создается кем-то снаружи, а не изнутри.

Comment: Почему в канонической реализации создается снаружи? Всегда создавал (C++) статический метод GetInstance со статическим локальным объектом класса и возвращал ссылку на него. В чем профит создания извне?

Comment: @int3 очевидно, в данном случае, экземпляр класса "брошен" на сцену в визуальном редакторе или что-то подобное. Зачем так делать - не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Это просто имя свойства, в данном случае переводится как "экземпляр". Просто так принято называть некоторые статические поля, особенно при реализации паттерна `синглтон`.